# custom label slot for vuetify v-text-field not registering

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When adding a slot for a vuetify v-text-field as per the docs here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#text-field
The label remains `undefined` and does not seem to register the slot.

Initially I tried simply `:label` for a dynamic label on the above component. Then went ahead with the custom slot which did not work either.

````
                <v-text-field
                  v-model.lazy="row.value"
                  @blur="rowSearch(index)"
                >
                  <template slot="label" slot-scope="label">
                    <div>
                      {{myLabel}}
                    </div>
                  </template>
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>```

Expected results is that the label will change based on some event in my component. Actual results are no label since it is `undefined`
````

Comment: Are you using vue 2.6?

Comment: yes using v2.6.7

Comment: simply add v-bind:label attribute to v-text-field tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `:label='mylabel'` in your template.
2. Make sure `mylabel` is defined in `data`, a `prop`, or a `computed` value.
3. Use `null` `undefined`, or empty string as default value.

I don't see all the code, but this has all the signs of `mylabel` not being `reactive`.

You can also define `mylabel` in Vuex and access it as `:label='store.state.mylabel'`, or by mapping it through a computed property.

Comment: My issue was that it was not defined since I put it as a prop instead of in data.

Comment: You can use it as a prop, but then the parent owns it and must define it.  You can also put it in Vuex store.

Comment: Yes I know, I was intending to use as a data attribute and mistakenly put into the `props` section so was not defined.

Answer (score 5):

Try `v-slot:label`

```
<template v-slot:label>
  <div>
  {{myLabel}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This was not it, I made a mistake and put my `myLabel` in the `props` instead of `data` (facepalm)